# Pidgin on windows can't transfer / receive files

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, pidgin, yahoo-messenger

I use yahoo messenger using pidgin on windows and I don't know why, I can't transfer / receive files. It always failed :(.

```
Windows: 7 Ultimate editions
Pidgin: 2.7.1
Pager Port: 5050
File transfer server: filetransfer.msg.yahoo.com
File transfer port: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [open](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12472) [tickets](https://answers.launchpad.net/pidgin/+question/97204) on the same. Perhaps attach you can help by attaching debug logs over at the trac ?

Comment: @silent: This bug report has since been changed to "fixed". If this resolved your issue, then you should accept this answer as the correct one.